# custom data attribute on table tag is not supported?

Tags: javascript, html

I tried this code but in debug test is undefined for attribute associated with table tag so is attribute supported for table or is my code bugged?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>data attribute on table</title>

    <style>
        table, th, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-collapse:collapse;
        }
        th, td {
            padding: 5px;
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        function testData() {
            var tableElement = document.getElementById("table");
            var test = tableElement.getAttribute("test");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="testData()";>
    <table id="tableElement" data-test="test">
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your function is faulty.

- I usually keep things simple by matching the variable's name with the object's id value. So id of table is also the var's name `tableElement`.
- When you are dealing with retrieving (get) a single`data-*` attribute, it is usually a string exactly like the attribute's name just like your function using `.getAttribute("data-test")`.
- If you are retrieving a list of `data-*`like with jQuery's `.data` or JS`.datalist` you drop the `data-` as you did in your original code.

  - It will be camel cased if there's 2 or more `-` in the name. `data-test-my-table` would be `testMyTable`

[**Details**](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) on `data-*` attribute naming syntax.

**Snippet**

```js
function testData() {
  var tableElement = document.getElementById("tableElement");
  var test = tableElement.getAttribute("data-test");
  //Just for demo (optional)
  console.log('data-test: ' + test);
  var out1 = document.getElementById('out1');
  out1.value = test;
  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  return test;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>data attribute on table</title>

  <style>
    table,
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    th,
    td {
      padding: 5px;
    }
  </style>


</head>

<body onload="testData()">

  <table id="tableElement" data-test="test">

  </table>
  <!---Optional--->
  <output id="out1"></output>
  <!------------->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The property name is `data-test`, not `test`. Consider using [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) instead:

> The **HTMLElement.dataset** read-only property allows access, both in reading and writing mode, to all the custom data attributes (data-*) set on the element. It is a map of DOMString, one entry for each custom data attribute.

Also your table element has id `tableElement`, not `table`.

This should work:

```js
function testData() {
  var tableElement = document.getElementById("tableElement");
  var test = tableElement.dataset.test;

  document.body.innerHTML = test;
}

document.body.onload = testData;
```

```html
<table id="tableElement" data-test="test"></table>
```

Comment: Although in this simple case speed is not an issue, [`dataset` is slower than `getAttribute`](https://jsperf.com/html5-data-attribute-dataset-vs-getattribute)